# Kafka Connector FilePulse Parsing Large XML File methods?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using File Pulse Kafka Connector i'm trying to load a 4GB xml file into a kafka topic in json format, the process is always filling the memory triggering a java heap space out of memory error in the connector logs, i've tried to use the property `"xml.record.xpath.expression": "/records/record",`
assuming that this would take each record tag and load it into memory on it's own , nothing changed in the result, my question is , is there a way for FilePulse Kafka connector to load a 4GB xml file without loading all of it into memory ? this is my kafka connector configuration:

```
{
    "name": "load-large-xml-to-kafka",
    "connector.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector",

    "fs.listing.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.LocalFSDirectoryListing",
    "fs.listing.recursive.enabled": "false",
    "fs.cleanup.policy.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.clean.LocalMoveCleanupPolicy",
    "fs.listing.interval.ms": "5000",
  
    "topic.creation.applicationlogs.retention.ms": "-1",
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": "10",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "3",
    "topic.creation.default.compression.type": "snappy",
    "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",

    "tasks.file.status.storage.topic": "storage-topic",
    "tasks.reader.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.LocalXMLFileInputReader",
    "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.partitions": "10",
    "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.replication.factor": "3",
    "tasks.file.status.storage.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.state.KafkaFileObjectStateBackingStore",
    "tasks.max": "1",
     
    "topic": "test-large-xml-topic",
   
    "reader.xml.parser.validating.enabled": false,
    "reader.xml.parser.namespace.aware.enabled": true,
    "reader.xml.exclude.empty.elements": false, 

    "file.reader.xml.force.array.on.fields": "<xml force array fields>",

    "xml.record.xpath.expression": "/records/record",

    "filters": "recordId",
    "filters.recordId.type":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.AppendFilter",
    "filters.recordId.field":"$.recordId",
    "filters.recordId.value":"{{ $.records.record.uid }}",

    "transforms": "CreateKey",
    "transforms.CreateKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.CreateKey.fields": "recordId",
  
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "<schema registry URL>",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "<schema registry URL>",

    "key.converter.schemas.enable": true,
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": true
}
```

here is a simplified sample of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
<record category="INDIVIDUAL" editor="" entered="2000-10-10" updatecategory="C4" sub-category="PEP N-R" uid="3" updated="2023-09-26">
<person >
<names>
<first_name>Mohammed Sani</first_name>
<last_name>ABACHA</last_name>
<aliases>
<alias>ABACHE,Mohammed Sani</alias>
<alias>SANI,Mohammed</alias>
</aliases>
<low_quality_aliases>
<alias />
</low_quality_aliases>
</names>
<agedata>
<age />
<as_of_date />
<dob>1968-00-00</dob>
<dobs>
<dob>1968-00-00</dob>
</dobs>
<deceased />
</agedata>
</person>
</record>
<record category="POLITICAL INDIVIDUAL" editor="" entered="2000-10-16" updatecategory="C6" sub-category="PEP N" uid="7" updated="2022-11-15">
<person  >
<names>
<first_name>Sadi Tuma Abbas</first_name>
<last_name>AL-JABBURI</last_name>
<aliases>
<alias>AL JABBURI,Sadi Tumah Abbas</alias>
<alias>AL-JABBURI,Sadi Tuma Abbas</alias>
<alias>AL-JABOURI,Saadi Tuama Abbas</alias>
</aliases>
<low_quality_aliases>
<alias />
</low_quality_aliases>
<alternative_spelling />
</names>
<agedata>
<age />
<as_of_date />
<dob>1939-00-00</dob>
<dobs>
<dob>1939-00-00</dob>
</dobs>
<deceased />
</agedata>

</person>
</record>
</records>
```

using the explode filter still wouldn't stream each record individually into memory , how do you load large XML files in FilePulse Kafka connector without loading the whole file into memory and causing an out of memory error?

Comment: process the file in smaller chunks rather than trying to load the entire file into memory at once. 1) Try process the file as a stream  2) Try to splitting the XML file into smaller files before processing.  3) You can also try to increase Java heap size, check KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS